# Search and replace in Array using index of another 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, replace, multidimensional-array

I need to search and replace through an `array` of `strings` using search and replace matches listed in a separate 2D `array`.

**--------Edit--------**

Final Code:

```
    String[][] searchLibrary;    // calls the replaces array from the LibToArray method
    searchLibrary= LibToArray();

    for(int i = 0; i <searchLibrary.length; i++){
        {
        fileContents.set(i, fileContents.get(i).replace(searchLibrary[i][0], searchLibrary[i][1]));
        }       
        }
    for (String row : fileContents) {
        System.out.println(row);        // print array to cmd
        }
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Use get() to access an ArrayList's items by index. Use [] to access a plain old array's items by index. The only ArrayList I see you working with here is `toSearchIn`, which you seem to be accessing just fine.

Comment: I don't see a 2D array.  I see a 1D array of strings (actually an ArrayList).  I think you need to clarify just what you want to be a 2D array, and how (do you want an ArrayList of ArrayLists's, or an array of ArrayList's, or an ArrayList of arrays?)  Then we should be able to help get the syntax right.

Comment: I have no trouble accessing the `array` to be searched.  I simply don't know how to search it using search and replace terms listed in a separate 2D `array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, first: You can define your `replace` the way you did (but change the names back to oldstr and newStr--or better, oldStr for consistency, with an upper-case S.  You can't start an identifier with a digit 2.)  Then outside, go through your 2D array like this:

```
String[][] twoDimArray;
// something that sets up twoDimArray

for (String[] row : twoDimArray)
     replace (toSearchIn, row[0], row[1]);

// or, using an index:

for (int i = 0; i < twoDimArray.length; i++)
     replace (toSearchIn, twoDimArray[i][0], twoDimArray[i][1]);
```

I'm not sure if that's what you want since I'm not clear from the description.  If I'm close, twoDimArray is an array of arrays (Java doesn't have "pure" two-dimensional arrays); specifically, it's an array of unknown length, where each element of the array is an array of length 2.  So twoDimArray[i] is one element of the array, and the element is an array of length two, and you can use 0 or 1 to index it.

Second: You may be using the wrong contains().  There's a contains() defined both for ArrayList and String.  Your code uses the ArrayList version.  For ArrayList, it will return `true` if any element of the array matches its argument.  That doesn't look right.  If you're stepping through the whole array, you don't want to search the entire array on every step.  For String, it returns `true` if the string *contains* the argument as a substring.  You'd have to write it like this:

```
if (toSearchIn.get(i).contains(oldstr))
```

since toSearchIn.get(i) is a string.  But I'd just leave it out, because if contains() returns `false`, replace() will just leave the string alone anyway, which is what you want.

Comment: I knew there was something wrong with the `.contains` I just didn't know too much about them.  Thanks for that little tidbit!  You've given me a lot of options here.  I was hoping to do this using an index as in your second example.  I'll get back to you once I've tried to implement this.

Comment: Using the index search I keep getting a "cannot find symbol" on the `replace`.

Comment: Which `replace`?  You've removed a lot of your original code.  Your original question had a `replace` routine; it's up to you to make sure it's in a place where it can be found, or to prefix it with the class name if it's a static method, or with an object if it's an instance method.  You didn't include this information, so all I could do was say "replace(...)" in my answer.  If you're talking about the String replace() routine, I'll need to see the code that uses it.

Comment: After taking a break I see those problems.  I've completed the code and posted it.  I tested the search routine with manual search terms and it worked fine.  Now I've adjusted it to use the "2D" `array`.  Currently it is compiling but not running.  An `ArrayIndeOutOfBoundsException` occurs.  I believe the issue is somewhere with the creation of the "2D" `array`, but I'm not familiar with that (The topic of my OP) to spot it.